# How to solve Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'getParameters failed (empty parameters)'

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, camera, mobile-development

I have a mobile app in Xamarin where a QR-code scanner is needed. Scanning the code works fine... After scanning a code, the user is redirected to another page. After checking out this page, the user is redirected to the page where the scanner is located. So, when this redirection happens, I get the error `Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'getParameters failed (empty parameters)'`... I googled for hours but couldn't find any solution for this problem. BTW, it also happens when I use the 'back' button on the emulator or real word Android device...

Comment: Add some code please because your question is not so clear

Comment: @AmjadS. thanks for your help! It was a long evening of coding, so I forgot to add my code. After some hours of sleep, I found the answer to my question. I posted it under this question... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--SOLVED--
Changing the PushAsync(pageX()) to PopAsync(); worked in my case. Found out that the problem is bases around getting the camera parameters. These are not available, because the camera is already using it in the former screen. So closing the camera/ending the camera activity is also a solution!